# What does "to pump a shotgun" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, definition

Is it "to reload" or "to shoot"? I figured out that "to pump bullets" means "to shoot", but I don't know if there isn't a difference with shotgun.

Comment: It's a specific type of reloading. A pump-action shotgun is "one in which the handgrip can be pumped back and forth in order to eject a spent round of ammunition and to chamber a fresh one" [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_action).

Comment: Neither, exactly. A pump-style shotgun is reloaded by inserting cartridges into a spring-loaded tube. Then, "pumping" the shotgun (pulling back and then forward on the wooden "pump" parallel to and under the barrel) loads a round into the firing chamber. Once fired, you pump the shotgun again to eject the discharged cartridge and to load the next round in a single "pump." So, "to pump a shotgun" is technically to chamber a cartridge, and/or to eject a spent cartridge.

Comment: This clip shows Sarah Connor pumping her shotgun: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=7V7OgZHhLbY#t=22. (Pump, fire, pump, fire, pump, fire, ...)

Comment: I believe you are confusing a shotgun's pump-action reloading mechanism (see answers below) with the phrase "pump them full of lead", which is a colorful way of saying to shoot someone.

Comment: By comparison, one would rack a lever-action long gun, cock a handgun, or prime a musket.   These are among the last steps before aiming and firing.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox It actually goes, top to bottom, crimp, shot, wadding, powder, primer (lower portion of powder and primer in a brass section called the 'base' or often the 'brass'. The wadding goes between shot and powder and works like a plunger pushing the shot out ahead of the expanding gasses. Often the wadding is plastic, looks like a cup of upward pointing fingers; these keep the outermost shot from deforming against the barrel as they move forward.
Oh, and it's not necessarily shot, sometimes it can be a slug, but if your barrel has a choke (a narrowing down at the end to improve shot patt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of the other answers are pretty close, but still not quite right. Pumping a shotgun doesn't reload it, and it does more than eject the spent shell casing. When you pump a pump-action shotgun, you are **cycling the [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(firearms))** - that means you are doing whatever the gun is designed to do automatically from a single movement.

This can all be pretty confusing to a person unfamiliar with guns, whether or not you are a native English speaker!

The firing of a gun consists of a few steps. First, you have to get a round into the [chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamber_(firearms)) - this is called "chambering a round." The chamber is the part of the gun that holds the cartridge in place prior to firing it. This might involve removing a spent cartridge if it has not already been ejected. Then you have to close the bolt, which makes sure propellant gases and the cartridge can't escape from the open chamber when you fire the round. Next you have to cock the hammer. The hammer is the part of the gun that is under spring tension and is released when you pull the trigger to hit the firing pin. After all that is done, you can finally fire!

The "action" of a gun is all of the parts of that process that happen automatically in response to one action. For a pump-action shotgun, that includes opening the bolt, ejecting the spent cartridge, chambering a new round from the magazine, and cocking the hammer.

"Reloading" usually refers to inserting rounds into the magazine so that they can later be chambered by the pump action. You can put a round directly in the chamber, and that might technically be called a reload, but in that case you wouldn't operate the pump action until after you had fired the round.

"Shooting" or "firing" is the act of depressing the trigger, causing the hammer to strike the firing pin which in turn strikes the primer and ignites the propellant in the cartridge.

Other types of guns have different actions. There are pump-action rifles which operate in basically the same manner as pump-action shotguns, but there are also bolt-action, lever-action, falling-block action, break-action, and gas-operated and recoil-operated weapons. Revolvers can have single- or double-actions - in a single action revolver, the next chamber rotates into the firing position when you pull back the hammer, and then you pull the trigger to fire. In a double-action revolver, the hammer is cocked and the cylinder rotates as you pull the trigger.

In all of these cases, the "action" is the part of the process that the gun does for you. Cycling the action sometimes has a common name based on what the most obvious movement is - pumping in this case.

Comment: This animated gif shows part of the cycle: http://i.imgur.com/CQcWpbk.gif

It is taken from a MidwayUSA video where the CEO makes a cutaway shotgun to show the inner workings: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uuMJ9grq-0

Comment: Also worth noting that many firearms share common characteristics and action types each model will have some differences in exactly how it does it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrBVZyRca1c

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the idiom "pumped full of lead," if only to point out that it's different.

Answer (score 21):

It comes from a *pump action* shotgun or rifle.

> A pump-action rifle or shotgun is one in which the handgrip can be ***pumped** back and forth in order to eject a spent round of ammunition and to chamber a fresh one.*

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIRaYXF_edg) on shotgun **pumping**. So you're not actually loading the shotgun, you're **ejecting** the spent round when you **pump** the shotgun. You can imagine that if you run out of rounds, you can pump all you want, but the shotgun will not be loaded.

Here, the person is [loading/reloading the shotgun.](https://youtu.be/ZwXpYpWOyfo?t=30)

Comment: According to your blockquote, "eject a spent round of ammunition and chamber a fresh one", and the video, the forward action of the `pumping` is definitely part of the `loading` process.

Comment: @USER_8675309 Chambering a round is usually done at the end of the reloading process, but that does not mean it is *part* of the reloading process. In fact, for safety reasons, a firearm might be reloaded and a round **not** be chambered, since a chambered round can go off fairly easily, whereas a gun without a round in the chamber would have to have a round chambered first before it can go off. A gun can be "loaded" with no round in the chamber, although "fully loaded" often means a round has been chambered and then one more round added to the magazine so that it is full again.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I agree on this -- I guess the differences are much easier to consider when you think about reloading a clip into, for example, a handgun.  Chambering a round is absolutely a different action from loading a clip.

Comment: Exactly. A clip is a removable magazine. Shotguns are not the only type of gun that commonly has a fixed magazine. I've fired .22 lever action rifles before that have a fixed, shotgun-like magazine underneath the barrel.

Answer (score 13):

Pumping a shotgun means to reload.  The action of pumping discards the spent shell and loads a new one in the chamber.

Yes, there is a difference as shotguns don't have bullets to pump.  It's conceptually different either way.

Comment: My opinion: to "pump a shotgun" certainly refers to the `chambering` of another round.  But there is certainly nothing to prevent you from "pumping bullets down range" while using a shotgun -- especially one that allows you to fire every time you pump it, like in this video: http://www.military.com/video/guns/shotguns/shotgun-demo-with-funny-ending/2525038464001

Comment: Sure, in common speech, you can "Pump 'em full of lead." with a shotgun or any gun.  But since a shotgun doesn't use bullets, there's not bullets to pump.  The pumping action though is unique to the shotgun, well, and air rifles.

Comment: chambering, not reloading

Comment: To clarify @njzk2's comment, firearms from the late 19th century onward feature a *magazine* of some sort - a place where ammunition is stored inside the body of the weapon in such a way that it can be *automatically* or *semi-automatically* moved from the *magazine* to the *firing chamber*. The action people take all the time in movies to prepare a weapon that makes a lot of noise is this action - it is manually actuating that automatic system. *Reload* usually means "put rounds in the magazine". *Pump* here means to move a round to the *chamber* from the magazine..

Comment: @USER_8675309 There is one thing that prevents a shotgun user from "pumping *bullets* down range" - shotguns are loaded with *shells*, not bullets. Shotgun shells have casings and powder loads like bullets, but ahead of the powder in a shotgun shell is *shot*, which is small metal balls, and then *wadding* ahead of that to hold the shot in the shell. It's called a **shot**gun for that reason. The idea is that the shot pellets spread out after they leave the barrel, giving you a better chance to at least hit your target with something. At close range it can be pretty destructive.

Comment: @ToddWilcox agreed.  Since we care about semantics here, if I could I would refine my comment to `pump (steel/lead) down range` or `pump rounds down range`.   And trust me, I am well versed in how shotguns work and how are they are intended to be used.  With your knowledge, I'm surprised you didn't point out that a shotgun could potentially be loaded with a slug, which somewhat defeats the idea of spreading out after leaving the barrel.